# Java Rest Put method is not invoked (Jersey/JAX)

Tags: java, rest, get, jersey, put

I am trying to invoke a simple Put method on my Java Rest service class with no luck.

I have the following Rest method and I attempt to access it at /classpath/new/newfooterm. However, this method is never invoked and I get a method not allowed error.

```
@PUT
@Path("/new/{footerm}")
@PathParam("footerm")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String createNewFooTerm(String footerm) {
    return "We just return footerm: " + footerm;
}
```

I have a corresponding @Get method in the same class and that gets called just fine. I am trying to understand what is wrong with my setup that prevents Put method from getting called. I access this at /classpath/all/.

```
@GET
@Path("/all")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONArray getFooTerms() {
    JSONArray fooTerms = new JSONArray();
            // do something to retrieve terms from db and store them in fooTerms array
            return fooTerms;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you invoking it? With curl?

Comment: Define "no luck" - what does the server return? Also, how are you doing a `PUT` to the server?

Comment: I am doing the a put by typing the pathurl in the browser. I get the following: type Status report

message Not Found
description The requested resource (Not Found) is not available.

Comment: I am very new to web programming so could have misunderstood something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a `PUT`. Typing something into your browser is doing a `GET`. You need to either create a test html page that does a `PUT` to your servlet or programatically do a put using Java, cURL, etc.

Comment: I see. Let me invoke that on my web page and see if that works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
@PUT
@Path("/new/{footerm}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String createNewFooTerm(@PathParam("footerm") String footerm) {
    return "We just return footerm: " + footerm;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why people write down answers and never explain anything about it. Its like playing jeopardy. Please explain to the person asking the question why moving @PathParam to the parameter will fix it.

Comment: I tried that as well with no luck. My understanding was that that should not make a difference. I could be wrong.